# Angular, send selector store data to child component

Tags: angular, components, ngrx-store

I would like to ask you about solution for send data from selector, store - ngrx, to child component.

It is only:

```
public testValue;

 this.store$.select(selectorDataTest).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.testValue = data;
        }
    );
```

and in template just:

```
<child-component [testValue] = "testValue"></child-component>
```

I think about `async` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `select` to get some data from the store it is returned as an Observable, (please use `select` inside a pipe) that's why you correctly subscribed to `this.store$.pipe(select(selectorDataTest))`.

This approach is better if you remember to unsubscribe, I have two approaches for you:

```
1.
dataSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSubscription = this.store$.pipe(select(selectorDataTest))
    .subscribe(data => this.testValue = data);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

```
2.
componentDestroyed$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSubscription = this.store$
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$),
      select(selectorDataTest)
    )
    .subscribe(data => this.testValue = data);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.dataSubscription.next();
  this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

And inside your `child-component` you have

```
@Input() testValue: any;
```

So your approach

```
<child-component [testValue] = "testValue"></child-component>
```

is also correct.

However, if you don't want to handle subscriptions, Angular provides you the `async` pipe.
Which accepts an Observable and subscribe and unsubscribe for you. That way you can just keep the Observable `select` returns you, like this:

```
dataTest$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataTest$ = this.store$.pipe(select(selectorDataTest));
}
```

and on your `parent.component.html`

```
<child-component [testValue]="testData$ | async"></child-component>
```

And, once again, inside your `child-component` you have

```
@Input() testValue: any;
```

Comment: Have I added sth? After it I have that error about : " Cannot read property 'xxx' of null". Like wrong flow data...